# RegEx to match specific sentence plus date and time

Tags: regex, date, sentence

I've tried figuring out how to make regex match something specific follow by a date and a time. I cannot for the life of me figure it out!

I want to match the following sentence, where the date and time of course may be random:

Den 25/01/2013 kl. 14.03 skrev

So it should match like this: Den dd/mm/yyyy kl. hh.mm skrev

Note that time is in 24-hour format.

Can anyone help here? I can easily find an example that matches a date or time, but I don't know how to combine it with this specific sentence :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it just by combining them as:

```
Den (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0{3}[1-9]|((?!0{3}\d)\d{4})) kl\. ([01][0-9]|[2[0-3])\.([0-5][0-9]) skrev
```

**Note :** Date not validated properly. Will match 30/02/2000

`Den` matches `Den` as such.

`(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/\d{3}[1-9]` matches date. `0{3}[1-9]|((?!0{3}\d)\d{4})` avoids **0000** as year.

`kl\.` matches `kl.` The `\` before the `.` is to escape `.` which is a special character
 in regex

`([01][0-9]|[2[0-3])\.([0-5][0-9])` matches time from **00.00** to **23.59**

`skrev` matches `skrev` as such.

**The following validates date a bit more well**

```
Den ((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(?=(0[13578]|1[02]))(0[13578]|1[02])|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)/(?=(0[469]|11))(0[469]|11)|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9])/(?=(02))(02))/(0{3}[1-9]|((?!0{3}\d)\d{4})) kl\. ([01][0-9]|[2[0-3])\.([0-5][0-9]) skrev
```

**Still matches 29/02/1999 - No validation for leap year or not**

**To match single digit days and months also, replace the date part with the following:**

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0{3}[1-9]|((?!0{3}\d)\d{4}))
```

The `?` makes the preceding part optional i.e. the `0` becomes optional.

Comment: Although, I can't get it to validate on http://regexpal.com/ if I input the sentence "Den 12/4/2012 kl. 14:41 skrev" for instance.

Comment: And I don't care about leap year or 0000, february etc. It's only to catch generated dates, not validate them or anything. It's to catch a reply header in e-mail.

Comment: @nickdnk I think "Den 12/4/2012 kl. 14:41 skrev" is invalid input, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. It does work on http://www.regextester.com/.

Maybe the other site is just broken. Answer accepted.

Comment: It does need to be able to match single-digit months!

Comment: @nickdnk Answer edited for allowing single digit day and month.

Answer (score 0):

```
`Den ([0-3]\d)/([0-1]\d)/(\d{4}) kl\. ([0-2]\d)\.([0-5]\d) skrev`
```

to catch the values in order to facilitate validation.

Comment: Naveeds edited answer is way better than mine tho, its closer to a full validation. my regex will allow 29 hours for example

Comment: I can't get this to validate anything at all...
Shouldn't I be able to input a full example of the sentence in my original post, and that should be caught in regexpal.com for instance?

Comment: Sorry, used wrong validator :)
But Nava seems to be on the right track though. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the smartest solution, but this expression should fit your request:

Den\s[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][[0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\skl.\s[0-2][0-9].[0-6][0-9]\sskrev

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I actually needed was:

(Den ../../.... kl. ..... skrev)

Since . just matches random characters, and because this sentence is auto-generated by an e-mail client, there is no need to actually validate if it's a date, but merely look for this pattern and discard everything after. Nobody would ever write that so specifically in the middle of regular text.

In case anybody is wondering, this is for SpiceWorks reply header filtering.